# Terrestrial locomotion of bats and pterosaurs

Tags: zoology

Bats and pterosaurs have skin attached to their forelimbs that aid them in flying and when they are on land, they use all four of their limbs to walk in a quadrupedal posture. Can these organisms be considered as true quadrupeds? Is there a different term used for this type of locomotion?

Answer (score 2):

[Quadrupedal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupedalism) means walking on 4 limbs, so yes bats can be considered quadrupeds. The scientific name for how an animal walks is [gait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gait). However, keep in mind that the same animal can have different gaits, think of a horse that can walk, gallop, etc. It seems that not all bats walk the same way, this [here](http://news.cornell.edu/stories/2005/03/vampire-bats-keep-out-trouble-running-study-shows) might be of interest, where they tell about a paper published in Nature in which they find a very different gait in Vampire bats, compared to 'normal' bats. In this paper they say that normal bats: "...shuffle  awkwardly from  a  sprawled  position." So I don't think they have a real name for a 'normal' bat gait.

For flying pterosaurs, it is hard to tell, we've never seen one walk.